# for loop in r is showing NA

Tags: r

I want to find sum of all elements in data frame 'a', but when I run the below code, it's showing 'totalcount' as NA. What am I doing wrong here

```
totalcount <- 0L
for(i in 1:9){
  totalcount = totalcount +sum(a[,i])
}
```

Comment: try `sum(a[, i], na.rm = TRUE)` in the loop.

Comment: @Suren I tried it, still "totalcount" is having NA_integer_ as its value. I also tried giving a zero value to "totalcount" before the loop starts, same result

Comment: You don't need a loop for this. If your data frame has only numeric columns, you can just do `sum(a, na.rm = TRUE)` to get the sum. If at least one of your columns is not numeric (e.g. a character column) then you need to convert it first, or you will get `NA` regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If you required to get the sum of all columns of your `dataframe`, then you can first convert your `dataframe` into matrix, and then get sum on entire matrix:

```
sum(as.numeric(as.matrix(df)), na.rm = TRUE )
```